# Is it thread safe to write different item of c array in multiple threads in c++?

Tags: c++

suppose we have an array

```
int a[2];
```

thread 1 only write/read a[0]

thread 2 only write/read a[1]

Is this thread safe?

Comment: While this is safe, you will have to deal with [false sharing](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/avoiding-and-identifying-false-sharing-among-threads)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the standard's [intro.memory#3]

> A memory location is either an object of scalar type or a maximal sequence of adjacent bit-fields all having nonzero width.
>   [...]
>   Two or more threads of execution can access separate memory locations without interfering with each other.

`int` is such a scalar type, and therefore each element of the array is its own memory location, meaning multiple threads of execution can access each of them separately without interference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe, in the same way that accessing two different int variables would be safe.